# Google maps won't work on my website despite good API key

Tags: google-maps, joomla, api-key

I had a website with google map, but few weeks ago google maps on my website stop working. I created google maps api key and entered it in my Joomla btgoogle maps module, but maps still won't work. What can be the problem?

URL Link: http://studiomob.rs/index.php/en/contact

Comment: I see this message in the javascript console: `You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.` (you are including the API twice, once with a key, once without a key)

Answer (score 1):

Upon inspecting the URL provided, I see that you have few Maps Javascript calls in your implementation which looks like:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?language=en-GB&amp;key=AIza...bLBZ8" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To fix this, kindly remove all your Maps Javascript API calls and just include one Maps Javascript that contains your API key which looks like the first one above.